# How can more Tasks share a common List in C# with TPL?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

How can more Tasks share a common List in C# with TPL?

I have a List and I need to divide the workload on more Tasks.
Each Task needs to take one element from the List and do something with it.
The first question is whether I decide how many Tasks to create,
or I let the library decide that?

But if I let the library decide that, then how does the List splitting happen?

Thanks

Comment: As one of the answers said, without more info, it sounds like a job for `Parallel.ForEach()`. For a great tutorial on TPL see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n). It actually covers `Parallel.ForEach` in one of the articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I understand properly, you can use the [Parallel.ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx). See an [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx).